# EF 7 + Oracle DB - InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query an Oracle database from .NET7.

I used database first approach to generate my model context. When querying, I get the following exception:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt16(int i)...

That's my (truncated) object class, and the property causing the exception (when I comment the property, select query is working):

```
public partial class Car
{
    public string? Owner { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Car" 
(   "Owner" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
    [...]
```

Generated context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Owner)
            .HasMaxLength(6)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("Owner")
         [...]
        }
```

Packages:

- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.8
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.1

What's the problem? Is it because the column is nullable? I have no idea.

**EDIT:**
Seems like the problem is the stored data. Some rows must be corrupted / not like the column definition.

**EDIT2:**
That's the LINQ query:

```
return await _context.Cars.Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt16(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method19(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CarService.Controllers.CarController.GetCars(Int32 plate) in C:\GIT\webservices\car-service-dotnet\CarService\Controllers\CarController.cs:line 45
   at lambda_method5(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You have shown everything except important things: LINQ Query and exception callstack.

Comment: @svyatoslav-danyliv sorry, added the information